# How to create multiple divs based on user entered values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I am working on a asp.net project and the main task involved is to generate a image div on button click.
as in retrieving image from database and showing it on screen(another div or table).
How can this task be accomplished?
I will be glad to know how to place an image on button click and then on next button click the next image should appear besides it.

Answer (score 0):

By using the following code you can generate dynamic div's:

```
HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

Now that you want to show images from database use handler like the following. Make an ashx file, add the code and then take an image control dynamically and bind the output of the image handler to the imageURl property of the image. The code is :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="DisplayImg" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class DisplayImg : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string theID;
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            theID = context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Stream strm = DisplayImage(theID);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);

        while (byteSeq > 0)
        {
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
            byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 2048);
        }
    }

    public Stream DisplayImage(string theID)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SERVER"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        string sql = "SELECT Server_image_icon FROM tbl_ServerMaster WHERE server_Code = @ID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", theID);
        connection.Open();
        object theImg = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        try
        {
            return new MemoryStream((byte[])theImg);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Just add one line in CS code

```
UploadImg.ImageUrl = "~/DisplayImg.ashx?id=" + code;
```

and finally add the image in the div

```
div1.Controls.Add(YOUR IMAGE's ID);
```